# How to add basic auth details in getUploadParams method in React-Dropzone-Uploader?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, authorization, dropzone

I am having trouble while adding basic auth details in getUploadParams method in RDU, can someone help me with this?

Here is a snippet of my code I am trying:

```html
  const getUploadParams = ({ meta }) => {
    return {
      url: "/api",
      param: {
        username: "admin",
        password: "password",
      },
    };
  };
```